# Unable to uninstall the SonarPLSQL plugin

Tags: sonarqube

I go to Administration > Marketplace.

For all other plugins that I have installed (SonarJS, SonarJava, ...) I see a "Uninstall" button to the right. For SonarPLSQL it just says "Installed".

How do I uninstall this plugin?

[image]

Comment: Stop SonarQube, delete the jar-file plugin and start SonarQube again?

Comment: Did you install this plugin? I see the same comment although I didn't install it.